# T-shirt Gift for Egyptian Muslim Co-worker?

Tags: practical-islam, clothing

I am in the United States and manage a team of data scientists, one of whom is a Muslim woman originally from Egypt. She wears a hijab (or an Al-Amira...I am not sure the difference).

I would like to get the team an end of year gift and was thinking a t-shirt sports jersey with name and number on the back, company logo on the front.

As I've never seen her wear a t-shirt I wasn't sure this was appropriate and want to make sure that whatever gift I give would be appropriate and something she could enjoy.

Of course, I could just ask her, but wanted this to be a surprise for the team...so thought I would ask this group first.

Thank you for any advice you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some Muslim women would not be comfortable wearing a t-shirt in front of men they are not related to. Some of these women might be ok with wearing a long-sleeved shirt underneath; others might not.

However, many Muslim women would be fine with wearing a t-shirt at home. There is a good chance your team member will appreciate the thoughtfulness of the gift, as long as you are not pressuring anyone to wear the jersey in the office if they don't want to.